# How can you structure Grails Services so superclass methods are non-transactional and subclass methods are transactional?

Tags: grails, inheritance, transactions, grails-orm

I have the following super class grails service:

```
abstract class SuperClassService {
    public def execute(def payload) {
        def tracker = new TrackerDomain().save()
        doWork()
        tracker.status = 'done'
        tracker.save()
    }
    protected abstract doWork(def payload);
}
```

and seveeral child class grails services that follow this pattern:

```
class SubClassService extends SuperClassService {
    protected doWork(def payload){
        new SomeDomain().save()
    }
}
```

In my controllers I kick off a call to the 'execute' method of the various child classes.

What I want is for the SubClass services to follow the traditional Service pattern where any problems get rolled back, but I want the domains created int he parent class code to both NOT be rolled back and be committed immediately (so that they can be viewed on a tracking page while the subclass service code is still executing. I would PREFER not to set everything as non-transactional and only set the functions in the subclass as transactional but if that's the only option here I would like to know that too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried annotating your subclasses service method with a `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`? I think that it should do the trick, regardless of whether the outside service code is transactional or not.

Comment: I haven't and will give it a shot but does that solve the second part where I want things flushed & committed from the super-class immediately?

Comment: I don't totally understand; do you want that the subclass service to be processed asynchronously, so the flow will go back to the parent class even when the subclass is still running?

Comment: Well, long-term yes. However; now you're talking about threading.  I really just want the TrackerDomain object to be saved immediately from the parent class and NOT affected by any rollbacks that may happen as a result of the child-class operation.